# (abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 + 1) / 100 as decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to I cast `abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 + 1 / 100` as a decimal?

For example if `abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 + 1` produces a value of 98, I would expect to get 0.98.

A try then gives only 1 or 0:
`,cast(cast(abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 + 1 as decimal)/100 as decimal)`

Comment: Integer Math is the problem  if you do math using integers, the result has to be an integer.  So 9/10 is 1.  but if you do math using decimals such as 9/10.0 then you can get a decimal result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can divide by 100.0.  I am guessing that you intend:

```
(abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 + 1) / 100.0
```